# Glazed China and Kashering

Tags: halacha

I recently kashered my kitchen and was wondering why modern glazed ceramic china had to be replaced, since the glaze eliminates the porousness of the china. When I ask people at shul, everyone says it has to be thrown away, but I found this article from the OU that has support for both sides of the argument from different rabbis.

https://download.torahtidbits.com/1378%20Pinchas/Torah%20Tidbits%20Issue%201378%20Pinchas%20Rabbi%20Friedman.pdf

I did replace the dishes, but in case I accidentally make one of the new ones treif, I'm inclined to follow the opinion that it doesn't have to be thrown away. But if I do that - can I not invite friends over because they won't see my kitchen as kosher? I'm confused by this subject.

Thank you!

Edit: To clarify - I'm referring to the Sheilat Yavetz where it says that porcelain dishes don't have to be immersed because of the glaze finish. From that excerpt it doesn't seem like a glazed plate and an unglazed plate should have the same treatment when kashering.

I'm also wondering going forward what do I do if I accidentally treif a plate. I bought a set of plates, so I'd have to replace the set.

Comment: I don't see anything about kashering in that article. And what exactly is your question? Are you asking us whether your friends are strict about kashering ceramics?

Comment: @shmosel hello, I added an edit to explain what I was referring to. From that excerpt it doesn't seem like a glazed plate and an unglazed plate should have the same treatment when kashering. I was also wondering if a plate out of a set is treifed, does it have to be thrown away

Comment: there is the shita of the chacham tzvi that if the china is cleaned and not used for 12 months it can be kashered by doing hagala on it 3x. This is not a widely accepted approach and most will just say to disgard. For someone that might be turned off from kashrus altogether because of this since they have sentimental dishes then a rav should be consulted to determine if this kula might be best for such a person.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. This site is not a good place for personal questions. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this. Also can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?

Comment: I think part of the issue is if it became non-kosher through the glass or not. If just the glass became problematic, maybe you can kasher it, but if the porcelain inside became unkosher (different ways how that could happen), then it's questionable if you can kasher it.